# How do I lookup values from a list in Excel and copy those files to another directory?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look at a list of values in column A and then lookup that value + an extension that exists in that folder + .jpeg extension and copy those photos into a specific folder.

My code only works in the first directory and does not copy from the other two directories.
The code is also really slow (maybe because of the photo size?).
I also need to make it dynamic so it looks up all the values in column A and not just A1:A4.

```vb
Private Function CountFiles()
strDirectory1 = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\005_SFEER"
strDirectory2 = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\006_SFEER"
strDirectory3 = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\007_SFEER"
strDestFolder = "N:\Decostar\AA Verkoop binnendienst\Z Hidde\Tes"
strExt = "xls"
 Dim myfilesystemobject As Object
 Dim myfiles As Object
 Dim myfile As Object
 Dim rng As Range
 
 Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4") 'set this to the range of your filtered list
 Set myfilesystemobject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set myfiles = myfilesystemobject.GetFolder(strDirectory1).Files
 For Each cell In rng
 For Each myfile In myfiles
 If Not IsNull(cell.Value) Then
 If myfile = strDirectory1 & "\" & cell.Value & "_5.jpg" Then

 With myfile
 .Copy strDestFolder & "\" & myfile.Name
 End With
 Else
 End If
  If myfile = strDirectory2 & "\" & cell.Value & "_6.jpg" Then

 With myfile
 .Copy strDestFolder & "\" & myfile.Name
 End With
 Else
 End If
 If myfile = strDirectory3 & "\" & cell.Value & "_7.jpg" Then

 With myfile
 .Copy strDestFolder & "\" & myfile.Name
 End With
 Else
 End If
 End If
 Next myfile
 Next cell
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the FileSystemObject [FileExists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fileexists-method) method to avoid scanning all the files in the directory.

```vb
Sub macro()

    Dim strDirectory(3) As String
    strDirectory(1) = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\005_SFEER"
    strDirectory(2) = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\006_SFEER"
    strDirectory(3) = "N:\Decostar\Algemeen\Website\007_SFEER"
      
    Const strDestFolder = "N:\Decostar\AA Verkoop binnendienst\Z Hidde\Tes"
  
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myFSO, myfile As String, myname As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer, n As Long, iLastRow As Long
    
    Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' list of files to copy
    For Each cell In rng
        ' check file in each directory
        For i = 1 To 3
            myname = cell.Value & "_" & i + 4 & ".jpg"
            myfile = strDirectory(i) & "\" & myname
            If myFSO.FileExists(myfile) Then
                myFSO.CopyFile myfile, strDestFolder & "\" & myname
                n = n + 1
                'Debug.Print n, myfile, strDestFolder & "\" & myname
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox n & " files copied", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: It worked the first time but now it says everytime i run it that there were 0 files copied. SO the first time the files appeared in the destination folder but now they don't anymore.

Comment: @HIdde Have you changed the active sheet ? Change Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet to Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname")

Comment: @Hidde Have you changed any of the code, the data on the sheet, the filter criteria or anything else ?

Comment: You were right. I have my macro's saved in my personal workbook and tried to run the macro in a diffrent workbook. I have to have that workbook open otherwise it can not find the macro's (really anoying). Is there a way I can tell it to use the last opened/used workbook?

Comment: @Hidde You could change ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: That maybe was a dumb question. Thanks!